# Найти кол-во нулей в строках матрицы. в строке с максимальным кол-вом нулей обменять с последней строкой

Tags: c++, c, матрицы

вот сам код.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int** poisk(int** a, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j, buf;
    int* b;
    int max;
    max = 0;
    buf = 0;
    b = new int[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (a[i][j] == 0)
                b[i] += 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (b[i] < b[j])
                max = j;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        buf = a[max][i];
        a[max][i] = a[n][i];
        a[n][i] = buf;
    }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j;
    int** a;
    int** b;
    cin >> n >> m;
    a = new int* [n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int[m];
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
    }
    b = poisk(a, n, m);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << b[i][j] << "  ";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А как ругается-то? У Вас после завершающей `}` функции `main()` лишние пробелы и символы.

Comment: Ошибку, пожалуйста, приложите к ответу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка происходит в функции `poisk`, потому что в последнем цикле Вы меняете строку с наименьшим количеством нулей со строкой `n`, которая находится за пределами матрицы. Вместо `n` Вам нужно обращаться к `n - 1`.
Вот так:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    buf = a[max][i];
    a[max][i] = a[n - 1][i];
    a[n - 1][i] = buf;
}
```

Также не забывайте очищать память, которую Вы выделяете с помощью `new`.